# Bootstrap Modal won't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am having trouble getting a modal to display.  I am using bootstrap 3.0.3.  When I click the button, the screen goes grey but doesn't popup the modal.  The css and js files are in the same directory as the html file.  I know this code works because I copy and pasted it from http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=activate-modals-via-javascript.  So this makes me think that something is wrong with the way I declared my css and js files in the head.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap Modals</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(".btn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
      margin: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
  <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Launch Demo Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal HTML -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3>Confirmation</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
      <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always place the script tags after the <body> section.

Comment: @Eisa Adil, This doesn't matter.

Comment: I never said it does. It's just good practice and speeds up your webpage.

Comment: By the way, check your console to see if there are any js errors out there.

Comment: Yes, it makes the page load faster, but I am simply focused on getting the functionality working.  I will then optimize my web page later.

Comment: The console says: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: When I type $("#myModal").modal('show'); into the console, it returns my modal div.  It doesn't display though, just grey appears.

Comment: @Eisa It's worth mentioning these things (within reason), but you didn't clarify that you weren't actually solving the problem at hand.

Comment: I figured it out.  It is because my code was using bootstrap 2 and I am loading in bootstrap 3.

Comment: I have the same problem here, grey screen appears but no modal. Seems to be a problem with `jquery 3.0.0-alpha1`. This new jQuery doesn't add the style attribute `display: block;` to the modal...

Answer (score 0):

You use class .hide at  that have styles:

```
.hide{
  display: none!
}
```

These rule always hide block

Better solution would be 
1. Add special class for this:

```
.hide-block{
   display: none;
}

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide-block fade">
```

2.The second way is to use inline styles

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" style="display: none">
```

but this is not so good as the first solution